# Как кратко при помощи цикла можно записать изменение числа?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как кратко при помощи цикла можно записать изменение числа зависящее от другого числа? Необходимо при значении из первой колонки выводить значение второй колонки, но заранее неизвестно значение первой колонки. Т.е. если вводим 12 то получаем 18, если 15 то получаем 20, если 16 то получаем 22.
Число меняется 12-18 разница 6, 15-20 разница 5, 18-22 разница 4, 21-24 разница 3, 24-26 разница 2, 27-28 разница 1, 30-30 разница 0, 33-32 разница -1 и т.п.

- 12-18
- 15-20
- 18-22
- 21-24
- 24-26
- 27-28
- 30-30
- 33-32

```js
const dlina = document.querySelector('#dlina');
const telo = document.querySelector('#telo');

function IsEmpty() {
if (dlina.value <= 12) {
telo.innerHTML = "18";
} else {
telo.innerHTML = "Ошибка";
}
}
```

```html
                            <input id="dlina" type="number">
              <button href="#" onclick="IsEmpty();">Клик</button>
              <p id="telo"> </p>
```

Я придумал только через условие if делать, но это очень длинный код и не учесть все значение.

Comment: "Число из первого столбца меняется на +3" - это неправда. 12-18 разница 6, 15-20 разница 5, 18-22 разница 4, 21-24 разница 3, 24-26 разница 2, 27-28 разница 1, 30-30 разница 0, 33-32 разница -1. Улавливаете логику ?)

Comment: Точно, спасибо исправлю )

Comment: А что должно быть для 10? Для 14? Для 25? И т.д.

Comment: Берется наибольший результат. Т.е. для 10 будет 18, для 14 будет 20, для 25 будет 28

Comment: Можете пожалуйста подробно объяснить почему для 14 будет 20?

Comment: Округление в большую сторону )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, просматривается закономерность. Числа слева идут с шагом 3, справа с шагом 2, сходятся ряды на 30. Поэтому можно посчитать кол-во шагов слева от/до 30 и рассчитать число справа.

```js
numbers = [9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39]
out = {}
numbers.forEach(left => {
    steps = (left - 30) / 3
    right = 30 + 2 * steps
    out[left] = right
})
console.log(out)
```

Comment: Но число может быть и 50 и 150

Comment: Конечно может. Если число не кратно 3, то будет дробный результат.

Comment: Спасибо я разобрался благодаря Вам )